# Adding second click event listener within a click event listener

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, event-handling, click

I'm trying unsuccessfully to add a second click event listener within an existing click event listener, using D3.

Basically, I have a map of events (circles).  I'd like for the user to be able to click on a circle and have a popup window appear.  I want that popup to only disappear when the user clicks anywhere a second time.  So, clicking on a circle would instantiate the popup and bind it, and clicking ANYWHERE a second time would make the popup disappear and revert the circles to be only responsive to hovering, unless one is clicked again.

I approached this by adding another "body" click event listener within the circle event listener:

```
  // event listener: if events (circles) are clicked, instantiate pop-up
  d3.selectAll(".events").on("click", function(d) { 
        console.log("event clicked!")
         //disable hover event listeners
         d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseout", null);
         d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseover", null);              
              popup.transition()        
                 .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);
              popup.html(d.ArtistBio)

        // if user clicks a SECOND time, anywhere, make popup disappear
        d3.select("body").on("click", function(d) { 
            console.log("body clicked")
            //hide popup
            popup.transition()        
                  .duration(200)      
                  .style("opacity", 0);  
            //revert back to hover, unless user clicks again!
            d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseout", true);
            d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseover", true);
            d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseout", function(d) { 
            console.log("mousing out!")      
                popup.transition()        
                  .duration(200)      
                  .style("opacity", 0);              
              })

            // mouseover event listers added back in
            d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseover", function(d) { 
              popup.transition()        
                 .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);
              popup.html(d.ArtistBio)
               
          })            
        })
```

My problem is that the events are both being fired simultaneously, instead of sequentially: once I click on a circle event, the body click event listener is also being instantiated, and so the popup is being removed as soon as it's being rendered.  Is there a way to do what I'm attempting to do, in a manner similar to what I'm describing above?

Comment: Could we get some HTML with this so i can run the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click will bubble up, this is properly expected. To avoid that, use `event.stopPropagation`. You can also use `d3.events` (while they exist...):

```
d3.event.stopPropagation();
```

Here is the demo, click on the rectangle and outside it:

```js
d3.select("rect").on("click", function() {
  console.log("rectangle clicked");
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
  d3.select("body").on("click", function() {
    console.log("body clicked")
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect width="50" height="50" x="100" y="50"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: PS: While this is certainly a duplicate, I could not find a good target after a couple of minutes searching... the issue is that I know the *solution*, and therefore, while SO doesn't;t have a search mechanism for answers, I have to look for a question whose solution involves `stopPropagation`, which is not an easy task. If someone finds a good target I close this.

Comment: Gerardo - perfect , the stop propagation method worked!  Thank you.  One more question:  if I want to prevent the popup from disappearing when user clicks on the popup itself: why won't something like this work:  if(this !== currentCircle || this !== ('.popup'){ //do some stuff here}

Comment: Basically, i'm wondering how to check if "this" click is either the current circle, or the popup itself, using a d3 class selector on the popup class ('.popup).

Comment: In that case it would be `d3.select(".popup").node()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
  // event listener: if events (circles) are clicked, instantiate pop-up
  d3.selectAll(".events").on("click", function(d) { 
        console.log("event clicked!")
        const currentCircle = this; 
        //disable hover event listeners
         d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseout", null);
         d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseover", null);              
              popup.transition()        
                 .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);
              popup.html(d.ArtistBio)
        // if user clicks a SECOND time, anywhere, make popup disappear
        d3.select("body").on("click", function(d) { 
    if(this !== currentCircle){
            console.log("body clicked")
            //hide popup
            popup.transition()        
                  .duration(200)      
                  .style("opacity", 0);  
            //revert back to hover, unless user clicks again!
            d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseout", true);
            d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseover", true);
            d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseout", function(d) { 
            console.log("mousing out!")      
                popup.transition()        
                  .duration(200)      
                  .style("opacity", 0);              
              })

            // mouseover event listers added back in
            d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseover", function(d) { 
              popup.transition()        
                 .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);
              popup.html(d.ArtistBio)

          })
       }            
        })
```

Inside the body event listener, check if the element clicked is not the same as the current circle/popup clicked.